# Charge through a time-varying capacitor

Tags: capacitor, capacitance, convolution

If a capacitor has a time-varying capacitance, such that C(t) = C_0 + Kt, where K>0 is a constant. Then is charge-voltage relation, Q(t) = C(t)V(t) = (C_0 + Kt)V(t), valid? It should be noted that here the multiplicative relation implies term-by-term multiplication of  C(t) and V(t) at any given time t. This ignores the mutual dependence of  C(t) and V(t) that arises because of the time-varying C(t). A continuously time-varying capacitance changes the charge Q(t) which in turn changes the V(t) across the plates. So the standard relation may not be valid here.

Or should the multiplicative relation should be changed to the convolution one in the time domain as, Q(t) = C(t)*dV(t)dt = (C_0 + Kt)*dV(t)/dt?

Comment: \$\text{d} Q= C\,\text{d}V+V\,\text{d}C\$ covers all. You can introduce time, at will, by dividing both sides by its infinitesimal.

Comment: @ Jonk. You are missing subtle concept that gets invoked on assuming C to be time varying. Q=CV implies for time-invariant system. But if C becomes time-dependent, it leads to time-variant system.

Comment: You haven't shown anything I've missed. But we'll leave it here, until such time as I see more than an assertion from you. It's your question. Have at it.

Comment: Wait for a day or two. I will explain it thoroughly to you.

Comment: @jonk See this, https://www.researchgate.net/publication/342702578_Charge-voltage_relation_for_a_fractional_capacitor